# Why does the flake8 error 'F402: import module from line N shadowed by loop variable' exist?

Tags: python, flake8

```py
import foo

foo.do_something()  # So it isn't unused


def test1():
    foo = 10  # OK
    print(foo)


def test2():
    for foo in range(10):  # F402: import 'foo' from line 1 shadowed by loop variable
        print(foo)


def test3():
    foo = 10  # OK
    for foo in range(10):  # Also OK
        print(foo)


def test4():
    values = [foo for foo in range(10)]  # OK
    print(values)
```

When I run this code through flake8, it gives me an error for the first line in the `test2` function:

> ./test.py:12:9: F402 import 'foo' from line 1 shadowed by loop variable

In the other functions I've clearly also shadowed `foo`, but flake8 is perfectly happy about that. So my question is, why does this error exist in the first place, and why is it specific to loop variables, rather than any variable?

Answer (score 2):

only in that one case did a **loop variable directly shadow** an imported variable

- in case 1: there is no loop variable
- in case 2: (this is the one)
- in case 3: it reassigns a local variable
- in case 4: this is a comprehension and not a loop

by the way, flake8 doesn't implement any checks, this comes from pyflakes

the rationale for this is opinion based so it's a bit off topic for stackoverflow, also it appears to be lost to the sands of time as it predates pyflakes being on github: [4301a8d](https://github.com/pycqa/pyflakes/commit/4301a8daf9d4f25004e8f77a51934dfe3bce195d).

it does look like the original code only detected this at the module scope and not in inner function scopes (which makes sense, module-level for loops shadowing imports is way worse than per-function shadowing) -- and it looks like that was inadvertently changed in this commit: [3d54e69](https://github.com/pycqa/pyflakes/commit/3d54e69e337481970faac3eae60ef35f4cfc6719)

---

disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of flake8 and one of the maintainers of pyflakes

Comment: To be clear, I was aware that the other functions either didn't have a loop variable (1 and 4) or the loop variable reassigned a local one (3). I was more asking why this error is specific to loop variables, which I don't think is opinion-based. I'm asking for the more historical reason it was added, which apparently is unknown. But I appreciate you linking to the original commit that added it.

Comment: the "why" of a lint rule is always opinion based :)

Comment: but yeah I think you'll find your answer if you read into the first one -- all types of module-scoped reassignments of unused imports will produce ~some error (such as `import x; x = 1`)

Comment: The "why" would be the opinion of the person/people who added the rule. I'm not asking for the opinions of people answering my question :)

Comment: I highly doubt mithrandi is going to (1) see your question and (2) remember what they were thinking at that time -- that's why opinions are off topic

Comment: I was hoping for a comment or a commit message or something to explain the rationale behind the rule being added. The fact that one doesn't seem to exist doesn't mean my question is off topic.